# how to change time from getID3

Tags: php, time, getid3

i have the problem about result strtotime in php from getID3, this result is 02:00:00 but i want to result is 00:02:00, how can change it ? please help and thanks

```
$durasi = getDuration($direktori);
$endtime = date('H:i:s', strtotime($durasi));

function getDuration($file){
include_once("getID3/getid3/getid3.php");
$getID3 = new getID3;
$file = $getID3->analyze($file);
return $file['playtime_string'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `playtime_string` returns minutes and seconds (m:s). So you have to add hours to it for make `strtotime` string. Use `gmdate()` function instead of `date()` to make h:i:s format.

Hope this will be helpful

```
$durasi = getDuration($direktori);
$endtime = gmdate('H:i:s', strtotime('00:'.$durasi)); /// make these changes

function getDuration($file){
  include_once("getID3/getid3/getid3.php");
  $getID3 = new getID3;
  $file = $getID3->analyze($file);
  return $file['playtime_string'];
}
```

Comment: why are the results so no additional hour? sample result becomes 22:02:00, I want the result 00:02:00

Comment: because playtime_string returns minutes and seconds format (m:s) and then you are converting it to strtotime, which is considering it to (H:i / H:m) and adding seconds itself after the H:m. So if we already passed hour value (h) to strtotime than it will not consider it to H:m. Now it will know as H:i:s